# Run linux program when two specific USB devices are connected

Tags: linux, usb, udev

There are perhaps 1000 or more web resources that explain how one can run an application when a USB device is connected.  What I'm looking for is a technique that qualifies an action on **two** specific devices being present (they can be connected in any order and at any time).  I've thought about a scheme where each device has its own action that creates a distinct transient file, then checks to see if the other device has created its file.  This seems cumbersome and may be prone to races.  Is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: Why not have them look for the other device instead?

Answer (score 1):

First, figure out how to trigger a program when USB devices are connected using those resources you mentioned.  Then write a program in C that uses libusb or libudev to check for the presence of both devices.  If both devices are found, trigger whatever action you want to happen.

Comment: C may not be required depending on what the devices are.

Comment: Sure, any lanuage that has usable wrappers for libusb and libudev would work.  And if your device can be detected in some other way (like with `ls`) you could do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking long-running processes from udev rules is quite difficult in newer Linux distributions, but leaving the particulars of that battle aside I took Davids advice.  Both udev rules invoke the same Python script, which checks for both devices and starts the application if they are present. It took a little bit of work to prevent races between two concurrent instances of the script, but I ended using rename of a file under /var/run/myapp as a mutex.  Still need a 'remove' rule to kill the process, but that's the easier piece.